# GWT issue fetching file from server

Tags: gwt

I have an issue in reading the csv file using  that i ve created in a folder in the weblogic domain. I am able to create the file but on click of a button i need to fetch that file and show it to the user

can some one help mw out pleaseeeee.  am facing an issue while reading the CSV file which i have created in the weblogic domain directory but ended up with the exception 
Error 404--Not Found 
From RFC 2068 Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1:
10.4.5 404 Not Found

/testDomain/CSV

below the code snippet

```
fileName = "CSV"+detailsMap.get("fileName").toString();
MessageBox.show(new MessageBoxConfig() {
                 {
setTitle("Alert");//Result


 // InputStream in = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(fileName); 
   //  final String file =in.toString();
    setMsg("Upload of Distribution Lists partially successful. Please acknowledge to find the failed entries");
   setButtons(MessageBox.OK);
   setWidth(250);
                                 setCallback(new MessageBox.PromptCallback() {
                             public void execute(String btnID, String text) {
                                 System.out.println("inside execute methoddd");
                                 Window.open(fileName, "_self",null);
                                 //Window.
            }
                         });
                }});`
```

Comment: Can you share your server side error/exception log if any? Also, ensure the path is relative to folder accessible by tomcat.